# Access specific column in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have this array events, which is a merge of two arrays.
The syntax to create the array is:

```
$events = [$events1,$events2]
```

Then the `var_dump` of `$events` array is:

```
array(2) (
  [0] => array(0)
  [1] => array(74) (
    [0] => (string) 
           Test1
    [1] => (string)   
           Test2
    [2] => (string)
           Test3
```

I try to access each sub array by doing:

```
$event1 = $events[0]
$event2 = $events[1]
```

This is not correct since it doesn't give me the desired output.
Please help.

Comment: _"the desired output"_ - what is the desired output?`(btw: you have $event1 then $event - a typo?)

Comment: hi do a var_dump($events[1]); regards.

Comment: @Jeff just to get them back as separate arrays. I combine them in the first place because I want the function to return two arrays instead of one. Now I want to separate them again

Comment: then do as you did, just correct the typo: `$event2=events[1];` (missing 's')

Comment: What output does this give?

Comment: @Jeff eh no it doesn't work aswell, I tried it

Comment: since we don't know what exactly you want as _output_ and don't know what part does not do what you expect it's hard to help...

Comment: @Manav the output of var_dump($events) is in the question

Comment: @Jeff So, I have two separate arrays, $events1, and events2, i combine them and then i want to get them separate again. I think it's quite clear what I am struggling with...

Comment: basically, I want to save the output of array(2) (
  [0] in one array, and array(2) (
  [1] in another one

Comment: So why isn't `$event1 = $events[0]; $event2 = $events[1;]` working? What result is this giving? What do you want if not that?

Comment: yeah, that's what you do already - except for the now corrected typo. But _where is the problem_?

Comment: Well, exactly, that's what it's supposed to do, but it doesn't. Both $events1 and $events2 return empty arrays

Comment: Oh it was a stupid mistake from my part, thanks guys...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make your array as associative array and Use foreach loop to get the specific value you want

```
$events = array('sample1'=> $events1, 'sample2' =>$events2);
foreach($events as $value){

echo $value->sample1;
echo "</br>";
echo $value->sample2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you have a Typo?

```
$event1 = $events[0]
$event2 = $events[1]
```

Comment: thank you for your reply, but it's not that. That's a typo of me writing this question..

Comment: If its not `typo` and answer not solve your problem then why you have accepted it? @AMAM